# How do I test the values passed as a parameter to a method inside another method (Java Unit Test)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Example:

```
public class myClass {
private WebService webService;
public void process(String delimitedString) {
    String[] values = StringUtils.split(delimitedString, "$%");

    insideMethod.setFirstName(values[0]);
    insideMethod.setMiddleName(values[1]);
    insideMethod.setLastName(values[2]);
    insideMethod.setBirthDate(values[3]);

    webService.getResponseWS(insideMethod.getFirstName,
                             insideMethod.getMiddleName, 
                             insideMethod.getLastName, 
                             insideMethod.getBirthDate);
}
}
```

I want to test that the right values are being set in `insideMethod` to make sure that the correct parameters are being passed to `webService.getResponseWS()`
This is in Java and I should use unit tests and Mokito.

Note: I am not testing the `webService` method. I need to test that the values passed to `insideMethod` are correct. Example "John" for name instead of "JohnSm" or "John$%".

So far I have created a test class, instantiated the class being tested and mocked the webService class.

```
public class TestClass {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        private WebService webService = mock(WebService.class);
  public void processTest() {
  when(webService.getResponseWS()).thenCallRealMethod();
    insideMethod.process("John$%J$%Smith$%02-02-1990");
```

Comment: You could put some `assert` statements between your setters and calling the webService

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`Mockito.verify()`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify%28T%29).

The JavaDoc aor the [Mockito Verify Cookbook](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify) lists a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private WebService webService; 

    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Test
    public void processTest() {
        // inject webService mocked instance into myClass instance, either with a setter
        myClass.setWebService(webService);
        // or using Mockito's reflection utils if no setter is available
        //Whitebox.setInternalState(myClass, "webService", webService);

        // call the method to be tested
        String input = "input"; // whatever your input should be for the test
        myClass.process(input);

        // verify webService behavior
        verify(webService).getResponseWs(
                "expectedInput1", "expectedInput2", "expectedInput3", "expectedInput4");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you've set up Mockito and injected your mocks correctly, the following should work (although I don't have a compiler or JVM at hand to check).

```
verify(webService).getResponseWS("John", "J", "Smith", "02-02-1990");
```

Comment: And remove your `when()` call. You specifically *don't* want it to call the real method.